# Receive server-sent event from android application

Tags: android, server-sent-events

I'm trying to build an android application that could receive the server-sent event.

I've already tried to receive with WebView and it works, but what I want to do is receive the event in android's code.

I've also checked following project but it is based on Netty framework(There will be a problem with the license).
https://github.com/andll/eventsource-java

Is there any way to capture SSE from android application?

Is there any way to create a broadcast receiver that could receive data sent from SSE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23101976/7972699

Comment: @Anmol I've already checked those links. Those libraries does not work without Netty framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not with java's built-in library, I had to use Netty at the end.